# Is there an optimum position for placing a bug or DOG?

Tags: editing, youtube

I'm creating some **How To** type videos to go online, and I'm looking to add a bug or DOG to the videos. The videos will contain some screen captures of a website with the full logo in the top left but it will not always be visible. I'd like to add the *glyph* part of the logo to 95% of the video.

**Is there any established rules or general consensus on where is best to place a bug or DOG?**

My first idea was to go top right (as top left would mean a logo over the top of a logo for parts of he video). This seems to fit with what most traditional TV stations would do. However I've notice a lot of YouTube creators have started to add them to the bottom right.

On most of my Google searches, I've only really found people asking or explaining how to actually place a watermark, and not any advice on where to place them.

Comment: The Vulnerability of Visible Watermarks https://research.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-visible-watermarks-more-effective.html ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a [bug or DOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_on-screen_graphic) and not a watermark for copyright protection, then the optimum placement is whatever is appropriate for your video's visual style. There is no magical location on the screen to place it. Most US broadcasters started out placing their bug's in the lower right corner, but that has evolved depending on the channel's look and feel.

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what I'm thinking of. I just didn't know it was actually called a bug or DOG. So essentially, no actual rule of thumb, just what works / looks good for you.